# how to do an self invoked AJAX post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post, vuejs2, iife

i am a bit confused about the self invoked function, i have done an http.get function to get the data from a json in this way (and work):

```
var Callmodule = (function(){
var urljsonEntrata= "modello.json";

function getmodules(){
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: urljsonEntrata,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    });

    req.done(function(data){
        console.log('ajax to '+urljsonEntrata+' DONE');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('-----------------------------');
    });

    req.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log('ajax to '+urljsonEntrata+' FAIL');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log('-----------------------------');
    });
    return req;
}
return {
    callGetmodules : getmodules(),
}
})();
```

i have done this because i want to use it in vue.js application, and i have invoked it in this way:

```
  methods:{
getModuleData : function(){             
    var req = Callmodule.callGetmodules;
    var self = this;
    req.done(function(data){
        self.modello=data;
        self.isLoading=false;
    });
    req.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        console.log('richiesta andata a male')
    }); 
}
```

now i have tried in the same way for the **http.POST** , but simply it doesn't work

```
var PostModule = (function(datadapostare){
var PostUscita= "http://www.website.com/filephp.php";
var datapost = datadapostare
function postquote(){
    var req = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: PostUscita,
        data: datapost,
        dataType: 'json',
    });

    req.done(function(data){
        console.log('ajax to '+PostUscita+' DONE');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('-----------------------------');
    });

    req.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log('ajax to '+PostUscita+' FAIL');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log('-----------------------------');
    });
    return req;
}
return {
    Postmodules : postquote(),
}
})();
```

and here the way in which i post it (consider it wrapped inside vuejs methods):

```
postData : function(){             
var req = Postmodule.Postmodules;
var self = this;
req.done(function(data){
    self.modello=data;
    self.isLoading=false;
});
req.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    console.log('richiesta andata a male')
});
```

}

why it does not go in done? and in which way i must pass the data object to post?

thank you in advance

Comment: That's because you're not passing any data? Your `datadapostare` and `datapost` variables are going to return `undefined` in your Postmodule.Postmodules request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using vue-resource or axios to handle http requests, it has a much simpler API as opposed to using the jQuery library